# Millimeters in boost::units

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

I want to use boost::units for some SI metrics. However our code mostly deals with millimeters and instead of using

```
quantity<length> value = 1*milli*meter;
```

we would prefer something like

```
quantity<length> value = 1*millimeter;
```

However I am not sure how to define "millimeter" (without using #define).

Secondly, what is the overhead in using prefixed units?

Update: This needs to run without C++11 features (i.e. no UDL)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using the following approach:

```
// your namespace name for units
namespace outernamespace {
    namespace millimeter_system {
        typedef boost::units::scaled_base_unit<boost::units::si::meter_base_unit, boost::units::scale<10, boost::units::static_rational<-3>>> millimeter_base_unit;

        typedef boost::units::make_system<millimeter_base_unit>::type system;
        typedef boost::units::unit<boost::units::length_dimension, system> length;

        BOOST_UNITS_STATIC_CONSTANT(millimeter, length);
        BOOST_UNITS_STATIC_CONSTANT(millimeters, length);
    }

    typedef boost::units::quantity<millimeter_system::length> quantity_millimeter;
    using millimeter_system::millimeter;
    using millimeter_system::millimeters;
}

// demonstration of usage
void foo() {
    using namespace outernamespace;
    using namespace boost::units;
    using namespace boost::units::si;

    quantity_millimeter mm = 5 * millimeter;
    quantity<boost::units::si::length> m = 0.004 * meter;
    if (mm < static_cast<quantity_millimeter>(m)) {
        std::cout << 'lt ' << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << 'geq ' << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

C++11 is indeed the easiest solution. You could do

```
static const auto millimeter = milli * meter;
```

or

```
auto operator"" _mm (long double val) -> decltype(val * milli * meter)
{
     return val * milli * meter;
}
```

There should be no performance penalty as long as you are not converting to other prefixes. And even if you do it should be neglible.

If you don't want to use C++11 you'd need to find out the corresponding type of the expression `milli * meter`, though you could just replace `auto` by `int` and read the compiler message.

Comment: It should be `long double val` (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

Answer (score -2):

If you have a C++11 capable compiler you could use [User Defined Literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) for defining your units.

```
double operator"" _millimeter ( double value )
{
    return value;
}
```

You can use that like so:

```
double foo = 1000_millimeter;
```

Comment: But this is not "real" millimeters, but only a suffix attached. I.e. all the functionality of boost::units is gone. E.g. conversion between meter/millimeter, knowing that Area s = 1*millimeter * 1*millimeter is correct but Area s = 1 * 5 is not.

Comment: Plus I need something that is not using UDL.

Comment: But this can easily be combined with boost units by returning quantity<length> instead of double